# ${}$ Conservative and Non-Conservative Forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

When we equate (with opposite sign) coulombic force to the centrifugal force for a electron revolving in the orbit. Basically we are equating a conservative force with the non-conservative force. Can we equate the two different categories of force. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Those two forces aren't equal as such, they're only equal within the limited scope of an assumption: that the motion is circular. If you do a proper proof of the equations of motion, the problem you're asking about disappears.

A quick look at the angular momentum shows that it's conserved, so the motion is restricted to a plane. Since the "centrifugal force" isn't a force at all, Newton's second law can be written in polar coordinates, assuming that the motion is circular:
$$m\left(-r\dot{\theta}^2\,\vec{e}_r+r\ddot{\theta}\,\vec{e}_\theta\right)=-\frac{k}{r^2}\,\vec{e}_r$$
Projecting this provides two results:

- $\ddot{\theta}=0$ so the motion is uniform.
- The radial projection provides the well-known result $mr\dot{\theta}^2=\frac{k}{r^2}$ from which you can derive other useful results like the period.

If you remove the hypothesis of circular motion, then there are extra terms appearing in the left-hand side, allowing more complex trajectories like ellipsis, and the equality that you were asking about no longer holds.

Edit: also, remember that this calculation is, in any case, completely artificial, since a real electron doesn't obey classical laws.

Answer (score 0):

You have met at least two problems at once. Let me try to clarify them. However, I have to anticipate that while there is no disagreement on the formulas, some disagreement persists among physicists about interpretation. The reason can be rooted in different ways of defining the force in classical mechanics.

**First problem: the status of the centrifugal force**

The centrifugal force appears only in rotating, then non-inertial reference frames. In the internal reference frames at the basis of Newtonian Mechanics, there is no centrifugal force. The only forces are due to interactions between physical bodies. A signal of the odd status of the centrifugal force is that there is no action-reaction pair: if we say that a centrifugal force is acting on body A, there is no other body on which an opposite force is acting.

Some people, mainly when teaching introductory Physics, would like to ban centrifugal and other inertial forces as confusing concepts. However, on the one side, it remains true that inertial forces in non-inertial reference frames could simplify a lot the description of some phenomena if used with care. On the other side, at least if we follow the traditional Mach's point of view, that force is nothing but a nickname for the product of mass by acceleration ($m \vec a$), we are forced to add inertial forces to the inventory of forces in a non-inertial reference frame.

The case of a circular motion is not so complex to justify using a non-inertial reference frame. We can work in an inertial reference frame and recognize that the only existing force between two opposite charges (the Coulomb's force) provides, for a given initial velocity, the *centripetal* force required to have a uniform circular motion. Only if we want to pass to the rotating non-inertial system we can describe the same situation as a static equilibrium where Coulomb's attraction balances the centrifugal force due to the rotation of the frame.

**Second problem: is the centrifugal force conservative?**

Once we work consistently in the rotating reference system, the centrifugal force is a force depending on the distance from the rotation axis, the angular speed of rotation, and the mass of the body:
$$
\vec F = -m {\vec \omega}\times ({\vec \omega}\times \vec r).
$$
For a uniform rotation, only the radial component differs from zero, and the modulus is $m \omega^2 r$. Such a force is conservative, and the corresponding potential energy is $\frac{1}{2}\omega^2 r^2$.

Turning back to the more general question, is it possible to equate a conservative to a non-conservative force (this is not the case for the centrifugal and Coulomb's forces)? The answer is yes. There is no problem. The quality of being conservative or not has to do with the way the work of the force depends on the path used for its evaluation. But equality of forces refers to the vectors at a point, not to some line integral. A typical situation where one would like to equate two or more forces is to find the equilibrium condition. There is a prototypic case where such an equation is done without problems: the analysis of the forces in the case of the limit speed of a body falling in a fluid. Gravitational force is conservative, while friction force is the prototype of a non-conservative force. We equate them without problems to find the asymptotic speed of fall.